# Как правильно сделать меню этого бургера

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

[image: Сдесь меню которое надо сделать]

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__container">
        <a href="#" class="header__logo"><img src="@img/logo.svg" alt="Change crypto coin"></a>
      <div class="header__menu menu">
         <nav class="menu__body">
            <ul class="menu__list">
               <li class="menu__item">
                  <a href="" class="menu__link">Exchanger</a>
               </li>
               <li class="menu__item">
                  <a href="" class="menu__link">Popular currencies</a>
               </li>
               <li class="menu__item">
                  <a href="" class="menu__link">Contact information</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <div class="menu__icons">
            <button type="button" class="icon-menu"><span></span></button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

```
//====================================================================================================
.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 50;

    &__container {
        display: flex;
        min-height: rem(90);
        align-items: center;
    }

    &__logo {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
        @include adaptiveValue("width", 238, 180, 1230, 428, 1);

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    }

    &__menu {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
}

.menu {
    padding: 0 rem(10);

    &__body {
        @media (max-width: $mobile) {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: #0F0D21;
        }
    }

    &__list {
        display: flex;
        column-gap: rem(30);
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;

        @media (max-width: $mobile) {
            align-items: flex-start;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }

    &__item {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        @media (max-width: $mobile) {
            .icon {
                display: flex;
                opacity: 0.4;
            }
        }
    }

    &__link {
        font-size: rem(16);
        line-height: rem(24);
        opacity: 0.4;

        @media (max-width: $mobile) {
            display: flex;
            font-size: rem(22);
            padding: rem(16) rem(16);

            &::after {
                content: "";
                background-image: url('../img/chevron-right.svg');
            }
        }

        & :hover {
            color: rgba(103, 102, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        }
    }

    &__icons {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
        display: flex;
        gap: rem(24);
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: end;
    }
}

//====================================================================================================

//Burger

.icon-menu {
    display: none;

    @media (max-width: $mobile) {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: rem(30);
        height: rem(18);
        z-index: 5;

        @media (any-hover: none) {
            cursor: default;
        }

        span,
        &::before,
        &::after {
            content: "";
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: rem(2);
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        &::before {
            top: 0;
        }

        &::after {
            bottom: 0;
        }

        span {
            top: calc(50% - rem(1));
        }

        .menu-open & {
            span {
                width: 0;
            }

            &::before,
            &::after {}

            &::before {
                top: calc(50% - rem(1));
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
            }

            &::after {
                bottom: calc(50% - rem(1));
                transform: rotate(45deg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что у меня не получается правильно задать стили для ссылок Exchanger, Popular currencies, Contact information Надо чтобы эти линки были в точности как на фото

Comment: Не очень понятно о чем ваш вопрос и что вам нужно. В таком виде на Ваш вопрос врядли кто-то ответит. Постарайтесь переформулировать Ваш вопрос, таким образом, чтобы на него можно было ответить

Comment: Нужно сделать такое меню, как показано на фото.
Структуру я сбросил, помогите разобраться со стилями

Comment: `-Видишь суслика? -... -И я не вижу, а он есть! ` так и с фото, о котором вы говорите.

Comment: Странно, сделаю ещё раз

Comment: И опишите в вопросе, пожалуйста, что именно у вас не получается. Ибо не очень понятно, в чем конкретно у вас затык: со стилями, со скриптом или вообще с понимаем того как взаимодействовать с DOM элементами

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня не получается правильно задать стили для ссылок Exchanger, Popular currencies, Contact information
Надо чтобы эти линки были в точности как на фото

Comment: Приведите стили для вашего меню, так пользователям будет проще вам помочь. Они смогут увидеть в чем вы ошибались и смогут подробнее описать моменты на которых вы застряли

Comment: Добавил свои стили которые я вписывал

Comment: Я уже в кровати, к сожалению, но в таком виде, на ваш вопрос уже смогут ответить. Если вдруг это не так и на ваш вопрос не ответят, то напомните мне о вас днем в комментариях

Comment: Хорошо) Спасибо

Comment: Доброе утро! Сможете помочь?